# Copying row(s) with the update on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table used by cms which holds data for several languages.
If i'd like to add another language i would have copy existing pages(all of some language) only with  a change value in column 'lang'.

How to copy row and change value of one column which will put to the same table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO foobar (lang,text)
    SELECT 'de',text
    FROM foobar
    WHERE lang='en';
```

Comment: Wrap the subquery in parens for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You'd do this with a statement like:

```
insert into <table_name> (language, value1, value2)
select 'new_language', value1, value2
from <table_name>
where language = 'old_language'
```

as per the manual:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html